# Retrieving only the latest item for a set of data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a set of data in a Postgres DB (but the data is DB agnostic). The data summarizes a set of security scans for a large number of project/date pairs. I'm trying to return a list of all the projects (unique) and only the most recent date.

I've been working on this in Python/Pandas, but now want to automate it as a SQL query.

Given a set of data of the form:

`id, project, scanned date, [results...]`

for each project, I want to return the most recent scan date (and relatedly - the results for that date. The results are all in a single row.

E.g.

```
id | project              | date       | vulncount1 | vulncount 2 | vulncount 3
1  | donutcalculator      | 01-01-1980 | 20         | 30          | 10
2  | icecreamoptimizer    | 01-10-1990 | 15         | 13          | 52
3  | donutcalculator      | 10-20-2011 | 20         | 100         | 2000
4  | snowmanmeltpredictor | 10-15-2012 | 10         | 11          | 12
```

I would like the following result:

```
donutcalculator,10-20-2011
icecreamoptimizaer,01-10-1990
snowmanmeltpredictor,10-15-2012
```

If it makes any difference, there are 100's of millions of records, but only about 6000 different projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT ON` in the query for that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (project) *
FROM your_table
ORDER BY project, date DESC;
```

The `DISTINCT ON` will shrink each different project to just one row. The `ORDER BY` clause must contain `project` and `date DESC` ensures that it's always the last row of each project.

Comment: That's awesome, and elegant. Love it! Much appreciated!